# Current month vs avg of previous 6 months

Tags: sql-server

Anyone know an efficient way to write a query to compare a current month's revenue to the average monthly revenue for the past 6 months?

Here's an example with just 2 columns, the actual month and the month's revenue

Columns:

```
MonthYear   RevenueAmt

Jan2017     120

Dec2016      75
Nov2016      50
Oct2016     100
Sep2016      75
Aug2016     100
Jul2016     100
```

so....the average of the previous 6 months (Jul to Dec) is

```
(75 + 50 + 100 + 75 + 100 + 100) = 500 

500 / 6 = 83.33
```

The current month (Jan2017) is 120, 
so the difference becomes-

```
120 - 83.33 = 36.67
```

So, Jan2017 is 36.67 higher than the average of its past 6 months.

Comment: Why is the average over ***`6`*** months divided by ***`5`***?  Why is the average for those months not `83.33`?  Also, is that *literally* how your `MonthYear` data is being stored?  If it is, you cannot use that column to sort the data... do you have any column you can sort the data by?

Comment: Should be 6, that was a typo
MonthYear was just for illustration, it's actually a date field and all values are the first of each month, ie, 12/1/2016, 1/1/2017, etc

Comment: Please don't change the data to make it pretty for us to read.  It drastically changes how you need to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the window functions and set the frame via `ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`

This is a rolling variance, and I did make one *modification*... I used an actual date so we can set the proper `Order By` in the `Over` clause

**Edit:** I added the Prior6MthAvg column to illustrate the math

```
Declare @YourTable table (MonthYear Date,RevenueAmt int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2017-01-01',120),
('2016-12-01',75),
('2016-11-01',50),
('2016-10-01',100),
('2016-09-01',75),
('2016-08-01',100),
('2016-07-01',100)

Select A.*
      ,Prior6MthAvg = avg(RevenueAmt+0.0) over (Order By MonthYear ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
      ,Variance     = RevenueAmt-avg(RevenueAmt+0.0) over (Order By MonthYear ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
 From  @YourTable A
 Order by MonthYear Desc
```

Returns

```
MonthYear   RevenueAmt  Prior6MthAvg    Variance
2017-01-01  120         83.333333       36.666667
2016-12-01  75          85.000000       -10.000000
2016-11-01  50          93.750000       -43.750000
2016-10-01  100         91.666666       8.333334
2016-09-01  75          100.000000      -25.000000
2016-08-01  100         100.000000      0.000000
2016-07-01  100         NULL            NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

I was going to comment, but it is more of an answer....
Please note: efficiency, and planning thereof, requires a broader scope of design.
 That said, in general - assuming a larger amount of data - the most optimal way (in my experience) is to keep a separate table for the "running averages."

To explain, I would keep a separate table (single record, if only 1 set of data - i.e. not company based), keyed by current month, with the given average AND the 6th month total.
Once done - insert a trigger for adding a new month (again, in general, or by company, if divided) that will subtract the 6th month, and add the current.
Then, either the total, average or both are stored separately, and quickly accessed.

Once done - a simple join will bring the total/average into any given query.

Edited to add: (NOTE: my T-SQL may be rusty, but this should give you the idea)
NOTE: it assumes the base table of ClientData, with a Secondary Table SalesAvg, linked by id (of the rep) and the date (the month marker, if the date can vary, you would need to split out month/year for the key and link). Pulling it from the same table as given will basically task the server at the point of query.  This method distributes the work to the point of insertion (normally more spread out) and as the average is keyed, allows for quickest retrieval using an inner join.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateSalesAvg  
ON schema.ClientData  
AFTER INSERT
AS  
    DECLARE @ID as INT;
    DECLARE @Date as DATE;
    DECLARE @Count as INT;
    
    SET @ID=new.id;
    SET @Date=new.date;
    
    SELECT @Count = ISNULL(RunCount, 0) FROM schema.SalesAvg
        WHERE id = @ID AND monthdate = @Date;
        
    IF (@Count = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO schema.SalesAvg (id, monthdate, RunAvg, RunCount, LastPost)
            VALUES (new.id, new.monthdate, new.value, 1, new.value);
    END
    ELSE IF (@Count = 6)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE schema.SalesAvg
        SET RunAvg = ROUND((RunAvg * 6) - LastPost + new.value) / 6, 2),
            LastPost = new.value
        WHERE id = @ID
            AND monthdate = @Date;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE schema.SalesAvg
        SET RunAvg = ROUND( (RunAvg * RunCount + new.value) / (RunCount + 1), 2 ),
            RunCount = RunCount + 1,
            LastPost = new.value
        WHERE id = @ID
            AND monthdate= @Date;
    END
GO
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following you, John.
 
We get a data file from a client and import it each month. Then we have to look at each sales rep's sales revenue for the prior 6 months and average it, then see how much this month (the latest month) is up or down from the average over the prior 6 months.

Comment: @Brian: alright - so either you run 1 table per client, or 1 master table.  For the LATTER - you would key the secondary table by client id.  So, assuming a master table client_data, with a secondary table client_avg, you would need to add a trigger when adding to client data - I'll edit the answer to clarify. (in a few)